# Windows 7 doesn't recognize DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, drivers, dvd

I reinstalled Windows 7 (x64) because DVD drive stoped being recognized. At first it worked, I even got to burn a dvd. Some time later it misteriously dissapeared again. This question has been asked and answered many times on the Internet, but no proposed solution works for me.

Please help! Any clues are gratefuly accepted!

**EDIT:** I booted a live CD and succesfuly tried to burn a DVD. When I rebooted back to windows 7 the DVD drive was there. I burnt another DVD and it also works... I don't know how much it's gonna last...

The drive is a TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-L632H. FW Revision: HS02. It's parallel ATA.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Need clarification here.. After reinstalling Windows 7 (presumably from the same DVD drive), your drive worked for a while. Now it doesn't. Also seems that it's not reading that's an issue, more writing. Can you do some troubleshooting yourself and clarify your question? Can you play DVD movies for example?

Comment: DVD drive is not recognized. No way to play DVD movies. I wouldn't have posted here if I haven't done a lot of troubleshooting before.

Comment: Has it got power? Does a disc spin when inserted? You said it worked temporarily as well. What happened when it didn't work? Did it stop spinning discs?

Comment: It's got the power! Discs spin. Booting from a live CD also works.

Comment: Is the drive IDE or SATA?

Comment: So, this issue was resolved? Care to answer+accept it yourself?

Comment: It wasn't resolved. Machine died some months later.

Comment: Are you sure the TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-L632H is Active (Enable) in BIOS? Can you see the drive in BIOS?

Comment: The computer died long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bad drive.  But before you replace it, you can try a couple of things.

Re-seat all of the connections - if possible, clean them, although with modern connectors that's pretty difficult.  At least clean out any dust.  You could try replacing the cable, just to eliminate one other potential fault.

Open the tray, and try to clean out the inside of the drives - I'd try a vacuum and maybe some compressed air.

If that doesn't work, it's probably time to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to checking the hardware, you might want to do a Windows Update and make sure that your whole machine is up to date. If there are any program/driver updates, it should happen when you run that feature.

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like what's happened to me with Nero, it's a bug in the software.

I don't remember how to reproduce it, but I remember my DVD drive no longer being listed until some rebooting pain.

Maybe try using something else to burn your files (eg. [CD-R Tools Front-end](http://cdrtfe.sourceforge.net/))?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to delete the Upper/LowerFilters as explained on various sites ([DVD Drive not recognized](http://windows7themes.net/dvd-drive-not-recognized-in-windows-7.html))

Another reason could be a corrupt driver. Try another driver source!

Yet another reason could be a broken SATA cable, download a cable probe tool or simply replace with one that you know is working

Yet another reason could be that some registry keys are set wrongly and always reset your permissions. Do you have a registry backup?

It's also possible some system files are missing, try to run sfc.exe /scannow (enter it into cmd.exe)

If all else fails, try another DVD drive to see if that one works